# Ubuntu 14.04 wired connection not detecting

Tags: networking, 14.04

dual booted Windows with Ubuntu a few weeks back. My Internet connection seems to be automatically detected on Windows, but not on Ubuntu.

Here is the output from ifconfig:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:17:7c:19:32:8d
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0                      
frame:0 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0  
txqueuelen:1000    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING    
MTU:65536 Metric:1 RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX   
packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX 
bytes:12609 (12.6 KB) TX bytes:12609 (12.6 KB)
```

**REVISED** Current:

output from /etc/network/interfaces file

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

output from sudo lshw -C network

```
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 00:17:7c:19:32:8d
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp    
   mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

output from dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e r8169

```
[    2.496839] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    2.496850] r8169 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    2.497073] r8169 0000:02:00.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.497194] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168e/8111e at 0xffffc90000642000,     
00:17:7c:19:32:8d, XID 0c100000 IRQ 40
[    2.497195] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx   
checksumming: ko]
[   11.058347] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.752240] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[   15.752255] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[   15.752283] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.752529] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

**I reinstalled ubuntu once again and now I seem to have a wired connection being detected...however there are still no signals on the wifi symbol at the upper right hand corner...tried all the steps discussed earlier...is there a way out?**

Screenshot : http://tinypic.com/r/2zohq0w/8

Answer (score 3):

If this is a desktop installation using Network Manager, then no declaration of eth0 is needed in /etc/network/interfaces. Network Manager should do the job perfectly well. Moreover, the file is slightly malformed. I suggest you edit the file as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Proofread, save and close the text editor. Reboot and let us have your report.

Sometimes, the troublesome r8169 will connect if you specify some capabilities, instead of letting the card and router negotiate. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add one line right above exit 0:

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot and, if it doesn't connect, let us see another paste as below.

if your system does not have gksu package by default use command:
sudo -i gedit /etc/rc.local

Comment: well it happens to be the same...i posted this question on <superuser> too...chk this for the screenshots
[link](http://superuser.com/questions/782311/ubuntu-14-04-wired-connection-not-detecting)

Comment: Meaning that you amended the file exactly as I suggested and rebooted and it still doesn't work? Your screenshot link is unclear on this point.

Comment: Yes I replaced the old one with the one u suggested and restarted ... It still says disconnected

Comment: Let's take a look at the driver. Please run: sudo lshw -C network and see what the driver is for the ethernet and then post the log output: dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e <driver> substituting the driver you found, of course.

Comment: As the logs will be long, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: link : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7934445/

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: sorry it still says disconnected ...
the contents of the /etc/rc.local file :
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7936250/

Comment: Is this changed? Better or worse? dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e r8169

Comment: It happens to b exactly the same

Comment: Please change as per my edit.

Comment: Disconnected still ... Added (speed 100) and restarted .... Btw shud I create a new network under network connections cos there happens to be no network now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16169/discussion-between-chili555-and-mrdoubtful).

Comment: Plz check out my new edit...reinstalled ubuntu

Comment: @chili555 I am having the same problems as OP. I followed the steps you have mentioned in your edit but that doesn't solve the problem. Using network manager in desktop ubuntu

Comment: @Azrael I suggest you start a new question and be sure to include your hardware information from the terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`

Comment: This should be marked as accepted. +1 worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding `ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100` to `rc.local` (as [chili555 suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/505862/22949)) didn't solve the problem.

But when I **executed the command from command-line (after bootup)**, `eth0` came up and DHCP worked. Maybe this will solve your problem too.

Comment: Hey so which command should I execute on the terminal again ?

Comment: I thought I was clear! Execute `ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100` as root user from the terminal

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work

Comment: oh okay. I am afraid I cannot of much help now.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to connect a HUAWEI E5776 and
using wicd

right-click wicd > wicd configuration
under wireless connection I chose **wwan0**
and *boom* I had direct tethering w/this device.

```
$ sudo ifconfig wwan0 up
```

may also have done the same thing, though a straigt `sudo ifconfig` was not showing **wwan0**

*About to reboot now and see it if sticks.
If anything changes, I'll update here.*